Script bash - Insertion of data into MariaDB from Oracle database
This script bash makes the data extraction to Oracle DB (another server), processing it and insert into MariaDB (my server), but the insertion it's misaligned and let it some columns in blank.

This is the code:
#!/bin/bash

ORACLE_USER="user"
ORACLE_PASSWORD="password"
ORACLE_DB="IP/SID"

MYSQL_USER="user"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
MYSQL_DB="DB"

echo "Fetching data from Oracle..."
ORACLE_DATA=$(sqlplus -s "$ORACLE_USER/$ORACLE_PASSWORD@$ORACLE_DB" <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP '|'
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
select TRIM(REGION), TRIM(CENTRAL), TRIM(NOMBRE_BANCO), TRIM(MODELO), TRIM(BATERIA), TRIM(TECNOLOGIA_ID), TRIM(AMPERAJE_CA), TO_CHAR(MEDIDO, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS MEDIDO, TRIM(PORCENTAJE), TRIM(VOLTAJE), TRIM(VOLTAJE_AC), TO_CHAR(CREADO, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS CREADO
from SIMBA_BD.VIEW_CENTRAL_MEDICIONES_PLOMO where rownum<=10;
EXIT;
EOF
)

echo "Data fetched from Oracle:"
echo "$ORACLE_DATA"

echo "Truncating the MariaDB table..."
mysql -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" "$MYSQL_DB" <<EOF
  TRUNCATE TABLE SIMBA;
EOF

echo "Inserting data into MariaDB..."
while IFS='|' read -r REGION CENTRAL NOMBRE_BANCO MODELO BATERIA TECNOLOGIA_ID AMPERAJE_CA MEDIDO PORCENTAJE VOLTAJE VOLTAJE_AC CREADO; do

REGION=$(echo "$REGION" | tr -d '\r\n')
CENTRAL=$(echo "$CENTRAL" | tr -d '\r\n')
NOMBRE_BANCO=$(echo "$NOMBRE_BANCO" | tr -d '\r\n')
  MODELO=$(echo "$MODELO" | tr -d '\r\n')
BATERIA=$(echo "$BATERIA" | tr -d '\r\n')
TECNOLOGIA_ID=$(echo  "$TECNOLOGIA_ID" | tr -d '\r\n')
AMPERAJE_CA=$(echo "$AMPERAJE_CA" | tr -d '\r\n')
MEDIDO=$(echo "$MEDIDO" | tr -d  '\r\n')
PORCENTAJE=$(echo "$PORCENTAJE" | tr -d '\r\n')
VOLTAJE=$(echo "$VOLTAJE" | tr -d '\r\n')
VOLTAJE_AC=$(echo "$VOLTAJE_AC" | tr -d '\r\n')
  CREADO=$(echo "$CREADO" | tr -d '\r\n')

REGION=${REGION:-""}
CENTRAL=${CENTRAL:-""}
NOMBRE_BANCO=${NOMBRE_BANCO:-""}
MODELO=${MODELO:-""}
BATERIA=${BATERIA:-""}
TECNOLOGIA_ID=${TECNOLOGIA_ID:-""}
AMPERAJE_CA=${AMPERAJE_CA:-0}
MEDIDO=${MEDIDO:-"NULL"}
PORCENTAJE=${PORCENTAJE:-0}
VOLTAJE=${VOLTAJE:-0}
VOLTAJE_AC=${VOLTAJE_AC:-0}
CREADO=${CREADO:-"NULL"}

echo "Region: $REGION"
    echo "Central: $CENTRAL"
    echo "Nombre_Banco: $NOMBRE_BANCO"
    echo "Modelo: $MODELO"
    echo "Bateria: $BATERIA"
    echo "Tecnologia: $TECNOLOGIA_ID"
    echo "Amperaje_CA: $AMPERAJE_CA"
    echo "Medido: $MEDIDO"
    echo "Porcentaje: $PORCENTAJE"
    echo "Voltaje: $VOLTAJE"
    echo "Voltaje_AC: $VOLTAJE_AC"
    echo "Creado: $CREADO"

if ! [[ "$MEDIDO" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
        MEDIDO="NULL"
  fi

if ! [[ "$CREADO" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
        CREADO="NULL"
  fi

if ! [[ "$AMPERAJE_CA" =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
         AMPERAJE_CA=0
  fi

if ! [[ "$PORCENTAJE" =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
        PORCENTAJE=0
fi

if ! [[ "$VOLTAJE" =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
        VOLTAJE=0
  fi

if ! [[ "$VOLTAJE_AC" =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
        VOLTAJE_AC=0
  fi

  mysql -u"$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" "$MYSQL_DB" <<EOF
  INSERT INTO SIMBA (Region, Central, Nombre_Banco, Modelo, Bateria, Tecnologia, Amperaje_CA, Medido, Porcentaje, Voltaje, Voltaje_AC, Creado) VALUES ('$REGION', '$CENTRAL', '$NOMBRE_BANCO', '$MODELO', '$BATERIA', '$TECNOLOGIA_ID', '$AMPERAJE_CA', IF('$MEDIDO' = 'NULL', NULL, '$MEDIDO'), '$PORCENTAJE', '$VOLTAJE', '$VOLTAJE_AC', IF('$CREADO' = 'NULL', NULL, '$CREADO'));
EOF

done <<< "$ORACLE_DATA" >> SALIDA.TXT

echo "Data insertion completed."


And the results are like this:
Region:

Central:

Nombre_Banco:

Modelo:

Bateria:

Tecnologia:

Amperaje_CA:

Medido:

Porcentaje:

Voltaje:

Voltaje_AC:

Creado:

Region: REGION 7

Central: LERFIC

Nombre_Banco: 7LERFICCT1B6

Modelo: BATERIA GNB ABSOLYTE, 100A-19 896AH

Bateria:

Tecnologia:

Amperaje_CA:

Medido:

Porcentaje:

Voltaje:

Voltaje_AC:

Creado:

Region: J10B                                                                                                                        

Central: TYPHOON(TY1)

Nombre_Banco: 0

Modelo: 2016-12-30

Bateria: 54.45

Tecnologia: 2.25

Amperaje_CA: 0

Medido: 2017-01-10

Porcentaje:

Voltaje:

Voltaje_AC:

Creado:




(1) Please provide example data exactly as output from your Oracle database and the corresponding output from your script. (2) Please frame a question so we know with which part of the issue you want help. (3) Please identify which of the outputs you show are correct / incorrect. You should update your question to include this information. Don't try to reply here in the comments.

I looked at this, and it's a clustershambles; we shouldn't fix that; the idea that you take unsanitized data from a database system, let the database print it as table, then parse that table in a shell script to then generate SQL inserts is just too complicated and error prone.
This could be a much smaller program in nearly any other scripting language, where you don't have to get the rows from the database query result as text and then split them back into the values yourself in the least useful syntax for that.
For example, in python you could just do the query and then literally go and insert all the results after filtering at once. Single line of code.
I'm afraid sometimes the honest answer to "how do I fix my shell script is" that you need to stop using the shell for things that the shell was really not built for.
There's other pitfalls that you would avoid by doing that and using the proper prepared statements instead of building your own insert(…) … VALUES($VARIABLE1, $VARIABLE2,…) string. Everyone loves Bobby Tables:

XKCD 237: "Exploits of a Mom" by Randall Munroe; under CC-by-NC 2.5
